# How do I pass subshell results (array) to an SSH command?

Tags: bash, ssh, psql, subshell

Trying it this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
myvals=`psql -d mydb -c "select id from table1 where 't'"`

ssh user1@host1.domain.tld "for i in $myvals; do echo \$i >> values; done"
```

As long as psql returns just one value, it works fine. But if its several values, I receive this response:

```
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `2'
bash: -c: line 1: `2'
```

Also, I tried to:

```
myvals='1 2 3'
```

And then it works fine: the values 1 2 3 are appended to the "values" file on the remote host; no error mesages.
If I try another subshell command, such as myvals=`ls /bin`, errors reappear.
It's clear that $myvals is evaluated on the local host already but what makes the subshell results so different?

Comment: _what makes the subshell results so different?_ Answer: there are newlines in your variable that screw up the parser. Try it with `myvals=$'1\n2\n3'`.

Comment: `myvals` is not an array at all in this script. Run `declare -p myvals` to dump its type and value -- if that outputs `declare -- myvals=...` it's a string; if it emits `declare -a myvars=...` it's an array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### If It's Not Really An Array...

Iterating over a string as if it were an array is innately buggy. [**Don't do it.**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) That said, to generate a safely-escaped (`eval`-safe) version of your value, use `printf %q`.

```
#!/bin/bash

myvals=`psql -d mydb -c "select id from table1 where 't'"`
printf -v myvals_q %q "$myvals"

ssh user1@host1.domain.tld \
  "myvals=$myvals_q;"' for i in $myvals; do echo "$i"; done >>values'
```

---

#### If You Actually Had An Array

```
#!/bin/bash
readarray -t myvals < <(psql -d mydb -c "select id from table1 where 't'")
printf -v myvals_q '%q ' "${myvals[@]}"

ssh user1@host1.domain.tld \
  "myvals=( $myvals_q );"' for i in "${myvals[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done >>values'
```

---

#### If You Don't Need To Store The Value Locally In The First Place

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh user1@host1.domain.tld \
  'while read -r i; do echo "$i"; done >>values' \
  < <(psql -d mydb -c "select id from table1 where 't'")
```

---

#### General Notes

- Running `echo "$i" >>values` over and over in a loop is inefficient: Every time the line is run, it *re-opens* the `values` file. Instead, run the redirection `>values` *over the whole loop*; this truncates the file exactly once, at the loop's start, and appends all values generated therein.
- Unquoted expansions are generally dangerous. For example, if `foo='*'`, then `$foo` will be replaced with a list of files in the current directory, but `"$foo"` will emit the exact contents -- `*`. Similarly, tabs, whitespace runs, and various other contents can be unintentionally damaged by unquoted expansion, *even when passing directly to `echo`*.
- You can switch quoting types in the same string -- thus, `"$foo"'$foo'` is one string, the first part of which is replaced with the value of the variable named `foo`, and the second component of which is the *exact* string `$foo`.

Comment: I guess OP wants to loop through the lines of the command `psql`... so maybe something like `ssh user1@host1.domain.tld 'while read line; do echo "$line"; done' < <(psql ...)` would be more appropriate.

Comment: *shrug* -- that's a judgment call, and the answer given here (particularly the `readarray` variant) *does* do what we both agree they're asking for (iterating over values on the remote end). Passing content out-of-band that way certainly does have its place, but it means you can't use stdin for anything else (including passing the script code itself).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, ...on further thought, it's well worth editing to add that option; doing so.

Comment: Very useful info, thanks Charles Duffy. Case 3 (without storing the values locally) works fine. But in case 2 I get this error:
./fence2.sh: line 6: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
./fence2.sh: line 7: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Otherwise, case 2 would be better b/c I need to send the command to more than one host.

Comment: @Charles, you probably meant a single quote at the end, as in case 1:  done >>values'  
That way it works.

Comment: Quite right -- I fixed that in the first example, but missed that I'd copied it as a template for the second; thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can send the output as a file:

```
#!/bin/bash
psql -d mydb -c "select id from table1 where 't'" > /tmp/values
scp values user1@host1.domain.tld:/tmp/
```

or pipe it to the remote host:

```
psql -d mydb -c "select id from table1 where 't'" | \
  ssh user1@host1.domain.tld 'while read line; do echo "$line"; done'
```