# Pass arrays to SSH connections

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, debian

I want to pass an array to a script that is on a remote computer. I'm using SSH for this. I tried the below code and I'm getting an error saying that the parameter is not available.

```
ssh -i location/to/keyfile -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -T ubuntu@18.220.20.50 ./script.sh -m 1G -s 0 -d 120 -w 60 -j 512M -k 512M -l 515M -b "${array_1[*]}"  -u "${array_2[*]}"
```

Here `${array_1}` and `${array_2}` are indexed arrays.

Comment: There is a similar discussion to your problem. Please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47490844/how-do-i-pass-subshell-results-array-to-an-ssh-command)

Comment: I think you're having trouble because the command is parsed (and quotes applied and removed) by the local shell, then sent to the remote computer where it's parsed *again*. But to suggest solutions, I'd need to know more: what're the arrays' contents like (i.e. can they contain spaces and/or punctuation that could complicate parsing), and how're they supposed to be passed to the script (it looks like you're trying to pass all values mashed together as a single script parameter, is that correct?).

Comment: @GordonDavisson I have several numerical values in both the arrays. If I go to the remote computer and then run the same command with it works fine. Yes, I'm trying to pass all values as a single parameter.

Comment: @jww I don't think it's very close to that -- the other question has to do with getting a string containing newlines treated as a sequence of words by the remote shell, but this question is about getting an array's entries treated as a single string by the remote shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the situation correctly, you have two arrays containing numbers, something like:

```
array_1=(1 2 3)
array_2=(21 22 23)
```

...and want to pass those lists of numbers to the script as space-separated lists, something like running this on the remote computer:

```
./script.sh -m 1G -s 0 -d 120 -w 60 -j 512M -k 512M -l 515M -b "1 2 3"  -u "21 22 23"
```

If this is correct, try the following command:

```
ssh -i location/to/keyfile -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -T ubuntu@18.220.20.50 ./script.sh -m 1G -s 0 -d 120 -w 60 -j 512M -k 512M -l 515M -b "'${array_1[*]}'"  -u "'${array_2[*]}'"
```

Explanation: commands passed via ssh get parsed twice; first by the local shell, and then the result of that gets parsed *again* by the remote shell. In each of these parsing phases, quotes (and escapes) get applied *and removed*. Your original command had only one level of quotes, so the local shell parses, applies, and removes it, so the remote shell doesn't see any quotes, so it treats each of the numbers as a separate thing.

In more detail: the original command:

```
ssh -i location/to/keyfile -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -T ubuntu@18.220.20.50 ./script.sh -m 1G -s 0 -d 120 -w 60 -j 512M -k 512M -l 515M -b "${array_1[*]}"  -u "${array_2[*]}"
```

has the array references expanded, giving the equivalent of (assuming the array contents I listed above):

```
ssh -i location/to/keyfile -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -T ubuntu@18.220.20.50 ./script.sh -m 1G -s 0 -d 120 -w 60 -j 512M -k 512M -l 515M -b "1 2 3"  -u "21 22 23"
```

The local shell parses and removes the quotes, but they have the effect of passing `1 2 3` and `21 22 23` to the `ssh` programs as single arguments. But then `ssh` just pastes the list of command arguments it got back together with spaces in between, so this is what it sends to the remote shell:

```
./script.sh -m 1G -s 0 -d 120 -w 60 -j 512M -k 512M -l 515M -b 1 2 3  -u 21 22 23
```

...which confuses the script.

My solution, adding single-quotes around the array references, doesn't change the local parsing (the single-quotes are inside the double-quotes, so they have no special effect); they just get passed through, resulting in this command being sent to the remote shell:

```
./script.sh -m 1G -s 0 -d 120 -w 60 -j 512M -k 512M -l 515M -b '1 2 3'  -u '21 22 23'
```

The single-quotes here have the same effect that double-quotes would (since there are no other quotes, escapes, dollar signs, or other special characters inside them), so this should give the result you want.

Comment: Thank you very much. While I was trying out I found another alternative way of doing this. Which is to use quotation marks including the scripts and the parameters. So the code would look like below.

ssh -i location/to/keyfile -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -T ubuntu@18.220.20.50 "./script.sh -m 1G -s 0 -d 120 -w 60 -j 512M -k 512M -l 515M -b '${array_1[*]}'  -u '${array_2[*]}' "

Answer (score 1):

another solution slightly different from the answers in [the question nominated by @jww](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47490844/608639)
idea is pass array definition as text;
and than eval them through stdin device
sample code piece below
you need to replace echo part with your own array definition script,
and put the `source /dev/stdin` inside script.sh

```
echo 'array_1[id]=3.14'|ssh  ubuntu@18.220.20.50 'source /dev/stdin; echo ${array_1[id]}'
```