# Avoid string splitting when transmitting arguments over ssh

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

To start a distributed computation, I've written a run script that uses `ssh` to login to a remote machine and start a script that it reads from stdin. However, this run script needs to correctly transmit the user-provided arguments from `$@` to the remote machine. However, I noticed that the arguments aren't transmitted correctly.

Let's say, the script `task.sh` that the remote machine should execute is

```
i=0
for p in "$@"; do
  echo "#${i}: ${p}"
  i=$((i+1))
done
```

This script simply iterates over the arguments and prints them line by line, e.g.,

```
$ bash task.sh hello world 'in one line'
#0: hello
#1: world
#2: in one line
```

My simplified run script `run.sh` now looks as follows:

```
ssh user@remote.example.com "bash -s $@" < task.sh
```

However, this will print:

```
$ bash run.sh hello world 'in one line'
#0: hello
#1: world
#2: in
#3: one
#4: line
```

When I quote `$@` with `'`, i.e.

```
ssh user@remote.example.com "bash -s '$@'" < task.sh
```

the following is printed:

```
$ bash run.sh hello world 'in one line'
#0: hello world in one line
```

Maybe, it's working when I use an array in `run.sh`?

```
ARGS=(bash -s "$@")
ssh user@remote.example.com "${ARGS[@]}" < task.sh
```

No, it also prints `'in one line'` in multiple lines.

Adding additional single quotes around `${ARGS[@]}` makes `ssh` interpret it as a single command and reports: `bash: bash -s hello world in one line: command not found`.

So, how to properly transmit the arguments to `ssh`, so they are split correctly? I guess, it probably works with environment variables, but can I also make it work without?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `@Q` operator :

```
ssh user@remote.example.com bash -s "${@@Q}" < task.sh
```

Comment: THIS is what I was looking for, a very simple and concise solution, thanks! Found an intuitive explanation of the `@Q` operator here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41940626.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass `"$@"` with double quotes around it to the remote shell. To prevent the local shell from expanding it, use single quotes around the double quotes. (Sic.)

```
ssh user@remote.example.com bash -s '"$@"' < task.sh
```

or equivalently

```
ssh user@remote.example.com 'bash -s "$@"' < task.sh
```

The array attempt would just push things around, not change anything; though when used correctly, arrays can indeed be helpful for solving this sort of problem.

```
args=(bash -s '"$@"')
ssh user@remote.example.com "${args[@]}" < task.sh
```

See also [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

Murkier still, you also need to doubly quote the arguments to the remote shell. One layer gets peeled off by the local shell, the other by the remote shell.

```
ssh user@remote.example.com 'bash -s "$@"' < task.sh hello world '"in one line"'
```

A more natural solution is to apply the extra quoting in the wrapper using an array.

```
#!/bin/bash
args=()
for arg; do
   args+=($(printf '%q' "$arg"))
done
ssh user@remote.example.com bash -s "${args[@]}" <<\____
    i=0
    for p in "$@"; do
      echo "#${i}: ${p}"
      i=$((i+1))
    done
____
```

with hat tip to [How do I pass subshell results (array) to an SSH command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47490844/how-do-i-pass-subshell-results-array-to-an-ssh-command;) and where I also took the liberty to inline `task.sh` as part of `run.sh`.

The original Bourne shell only had `$*` which suffered from exactly this problem. The fix was to introduce `$@` which differs *only* when it is explicitly invoked with double quotes around it. This is a pretty murky corner case of the *Bourne legacy.*

Comment: But wouldn't this result in the command `bash -s "$@"` executed on the remote end? Or would it transmit the local arguments correctly?

Comment: Huh? You literally want that to be executed remotely.

Comment: I tried it, but it apparently doesn't print anything.

Comment: I want the content of `$@` to be transmitted as arguments to `task.sh` on the remote end the same way the run script `run.sh` received them, not literally `'$@'`.

Comment: See update just now.

Comment: I see, so you first escape the content of each single argument, then pass them to ssh as an array. Thank you!